# Как с помощью .append вставить содержимое другого файла?

Tags: jquery

Что нужно писать в скобках .append, чтобы вставить содержимое другого файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала это содержимое надо загрузить. Посмотрите [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)